# How do I use MathJax?

Tags: support, mathjax

It has become apparent to me and many here that I don't understand MathJax inputs. I primarily just need to understand how to input calculus problems. Can anybody put me on the right path to understanding how to do this?

How do I write Integrals and Limits, for example?

Answer (score 1):

When I was learning how to write in LaTeX, I typically just searched "latex MATH-THING", where MATH-THING was what I wanted to write. You'd be surprised at how far this gets you. You might often find yourself on [this site](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics).

Aside from that, you can use some of the tips MSE offers in its help sections. Also, try clicking "Edit" beneath a person's post to see how they achieved one or another symbol.

To answer your specific question, the integral $\int_a^b f(x) \ dx$ is written as

> \int_a^b f(x) \ dx

and the limit $\lim_ {x \to a} f(x)$ is written

> \lim_{x \to a} f(x).

Both of these examples are surrounded by $s in order to beautify them.